# Setting negative bottom property in css extends bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to hide part of an html element in the bottom of the page and then reveal the whole thing by sliding it upward on click via CSS3 transitions.

Normally, what should happen is the part of the element that extends below the page is just hidden However, what's happening is that the page is just being extended to show that part of element.

How do I fix this?

Heres my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="closed" id="slidePanel">
    <div id="slidePanel-tab">
            Stuff
    </div>
    <div id="slidePanel-contents">
        <ol>
            <li>stuff</li>
            <li>stuff</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#slidePanel {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 66px);   
    z-index: 2;
    min-width: 10%;
    min-height: 20%;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);

    -webkit-transition: bottom 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: bottom 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#slidePanel.closed {
    bottom: calc(-20% + 20px);

    -webkit-transition: bottom 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: bottom 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#slidePanel-tab {
    background-color: #d0d0d0;
}

$("#slidePanel-tab").click(function (evt) {
    $("#slidePanel").toggleClass("closed");

    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Heres an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/sd306pyr/

Comment: body {overflow:hidden;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the element's position to `fixed`:

```
#slidePanel {
background-color: #e9e9e9;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: calc(50% - 66px);   
z-index: 2;
min-width: 10%;/*30%; */
min-height: 20%;
border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .05); 
-webkit-transition: bottom 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: bottom 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sd306pyr/2/

You can also set the `overflow` of the element's container to `hidden` as pointed out in the comments to your question. Whatever works better with the layout of your DOM as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the javascript script that sets the **display** to **none** after transition is done and set **body overflow to hidden**.